# Process using more memory than I physically have

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I'm loading a 4GB csv in Python using pandas, and activity monitor says I'm using more RAM than I physically have in my laptop (15GB out of 8GB). How's this possible internally?

[image: I need to download more RAM]

Comment: Shortly: swap file is used to extend your physical RAM

Comment: check this quesiton,might help  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97341/why-is-my-mac-using-so-much-memory/125707#125707

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This guy explains it well http://www.chriswrites.com/what-is-virtual-memory-on-the-mac/

> So What is Virtual Memory?
>
> Your Mac comes with a limited amount of
>   physical memory (RAM) installed by default. Memory is critical to any
>   computer to run applications and carry out all the operations
>   commanded by the user. Memory must be as fast as possible (and it
>   helps to have as much as possible) to maximise your Mac’s performance;
>   thankfully, prices have drastically fallen in recent years.
>   Nevertheless, every computer has a finite amount of memory so Mac OS X
>   might actually need to use more than is physically available on your
>   system.
>
> This is where virtual memory comes in – you can think of it as a kind
>   of extension to the real memory on your system, albeit much slower
>   because it is in fact physical space on your hard disk (or SSD, if you
>   have one installed). Let’s say that you have 4 GB of main memory on
>   your Mac and a 512 GB hard disk. If Mac OS X needs to use all 4 GB of
>   main memory, it can still make use of any free space on your hard disk
>   as an extension to that memory. Unfortunately, virtual memory is much
>   slower than the physical RAM installed in your computer, because hard
>   disks cannot match the speed of memory chips.

Comment: got it, thanks. As an aside, if I wanted to manipulate 100GB csv files, could I install linux with a gigantic swap partition?

Comment: Yes but your system will slow down because some of the system procs will also swap. The right technique is to manipulate big files efficiently ;) eg striping your reading.