# What features of Mavericks are beneficial to you?

Tags: macos

This question serves to share and collect the enhancements that make a large difference to how you use your Mac.

Please post **one feature per answer**. Please also check to see if your answer has already been posted - duplicate answers will be deleted. To search answers for this question use [`inquestion:this`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion:this) (directly from the question page) in addition to your search terms in the search box in the upper right hand corner of this page.

The best answers will not only list a feature, but provide details on how to configure that feature, and provide an image of how to use the feature to be more efficient or effective with Mavericks.

Comment: As always - questions about site norms and governance are best asked on [meta] since the comments here became dominated with what's on or off-topic here or on other sites. Meta allows a more careful discussion of the problems and merits of wiki questions - both in general and in specific here. Cheers and thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The overhaul of the virtual memory system makes it clear that memory pressure is the primary factor to track and not how many free pages, inactive pages or overall virtual memory is allocated.

[image: Mavericks Activity Monitor - memory]

The bottom panel is invaluable for diagnosing a slow machine and knowing whether to rule out memory contention as a cause of the slowness. After running your Mac for a week, you should reach a nice steady state like shown above and can know if adding more RAM or adjusting the programs you run will affect performance.

Comment: And, best of all, this feature renders moot all the [angst](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/67031/isnt-inactive-memory-a-waste-of-resources) and [confusion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52013/why-is-it-that-my-mac-would-rather-swap-than-clear-inactive-memory) about [inactive memory](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11403/trouble-understanding-inactive-memory-in-macosx) on OS X. Boom!

Comment: Even more it compresses the memory - so I have 1G of swap files rather than 8-10G, or is that a separate entry

Comment: @mark I have never had swap storage issues so I can't say how well it will reduce swap allocations but the signs are promising so far.

Comment: It has improved mine so far

Comment: 750MB for the *kernel*?!!!

Comment: @sds I know - here's more details on the memory allocation. That 650-800 MB for the kernel seems to be a very stable estimate on what we'll see on Mavericks and newish Intel CPU. http://cl.ly/S5NO

Comment: @sds video memory for onboard integrated graphics is marked as used by kernel as well. That used memory has to be attributed somewhere...

Comment: @EugeneBujak: r u sure video memory is included there?

Comment: I would encourage either Eugene or SDS to explicitly ask what is included in kernel_task as a stand-alone question. We can't really answer a question posed in a comment.

Comment: @bmike: [What is included under `kernel_task` in Activity Monitor?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106444/what-is-included-under-kernel-task-in-activity-monitor)

Comment: @sds, kernel takes 9GB for me http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106697/insanely-high-kernel-ram-usage-over-9gb-in-mavericks

Comment: @sds 1.8GB here

Answer (score 47):

With a text field active, <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> opens a characters panel including Emojis.

[image]

Comment: Does not work in MS Word :(

Comment: Very few things work in MS Word - I think they use a custom text engine or something.

Comment: A panel opens even without a text field selected (in Finder for example), so it should be possible to drag and drop a character that way.

Comment: It is not just emoji, but a quicker better way to search for any unicode character like: , ÷, ∪, or Δ

Comment: While I agree it is a nice feature, they should have sticked with the old shortcut Cmd + Shift + T. In fact, it was the first thing I changed on Mavericks.

Comment: Good thing we have such quick access to the recycle symbols.

Answer (score 44):

The energy consumption view that collects 8 hours of history and graphs the charge level in your battery as well as showing each process that drained measurable amounts of energy is going to make squeezing extra productivity out of one charge much easier.

[image: energy usage - 8 hours]

Not only will developers *(I'm looking at you Dropbox)* know that they have to be better stewards of battery life, it makes it easy to see which apps support App Nap and even that a program that is quit now was responsible for using energy in the past 8 hours. This tool provides actionable information for users to better manage their experience when away from wall power on a portable Mac.

This detail is quite hidden inside Activity Monitor, but Apple does expose the biggest users of energy in the menu bar for apps using significant energy.

[image: undo is unicode U+238c or &#9100]

Comment: What is AppNap exactly ?

Answer (score 41):

### Secret Wallpapers

OS X ships with a bunch of really cool sample photos that are not normally available for use as desktop backgrounds.

Previously in OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, these were located at:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.Framework/Versions/A/Resources/Default Collections/
```

In OS X 10.9 Mavericks, they’re now located at

```
/Library/Screen Savers/Default Collections/
```

Here's how to get them:

- from Finder, use the menu **Go** → **Go to Folder**… (**or hit ⌘⇧G**) and paste in: `/Library/Screen Savers/Default Collections/`

You should see 4 folders, and inside them you’ll find lots of really cool Wallpapers:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Note a slight change to the Mountain Lion address: /System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Default Collections/

Answer (score 41):

**Bring Your Home Folder's Library Back with One Checkbox in Mavericks:**

Apple decided to hide the Library from its users in recent OS X updates, but in Mavericks you can now change that with a simple checkbox.

In the past you had to enter a Terminal command with every little system update:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

With OS X Mavericks, you can just navigate to your home folder, press **Command+J** to bring up the folder settings, and check the box next to **"Show Library Folder"** instead.

Comment: Great answer - we have a more targeted question covering this aspect over there -> http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106645/how-do-i-tell-finder-to-always-show-my-library-folder-on-mavericks

Answer (score 36):

### Put your computer to sleep quickly

If you're using OSX Mavericks on a MacBook, tapping the <kbd>power</kbd> key briefly immediately puts your computer to sleep—a simple tweak that makes saving energy even easier.  For the usual shutdown dialog, just keep holding for three seconds, or press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>power</kbd>.

As always, you can put just the display to sleep by pressing <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>eject</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>power</kbd>, depending on your model.

Comment: I've always used a hot-corner for that, and I think I still prefer it that way.

Comment: @Elliott Good thinking.

Comment: Not shutting the computer down when someone just taps the power button is going to make life with a cheeky 3-year-old easier! :-)

Comment: It's control + shutdown button for the dialog, 3 second hold is immediate shutdown.

Comment: not only turns off the display, but also locks the computer.

Comment: ctrl+shift+eject since (at least) 10.6

Comment: As pointed out by Filip, `ctrl+shift+eject` has been around for years. I don't think many users know this shortcut though. Most people are just bad at shortcuts.

Comment: and Airs don't have an eject key

Comment: Ctrl+shift+power instead of eject works for MacBook Air (at least on a Mid-2012)

Comment: ctrl + shift + eject(or power where no eject key) turns off the *display* - power key sleeps the Mac.

Comment: ooooooooh, is THAT what's going on now when I hit the power button?  Very confusing change if you're expecting the shutdown dialog box.

Answer (score 36):

Using multiple desktops on multiple displays is *finally* usable. Now I can switch desktops on my left hand monitor while the right hand monitor doesn't change.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this has changed from Mountain Lion?

Comment: Put a Safari window on both displays. Cover them both with Finder windows. Now, on the left monitor, bring the Safari window to the foreground... pre-Mavericks, it would bring Safari to the foreground on both monitors. Maybe that's not what he's describing, but if it is I too find this a boon to my productivity.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call this an under documented feature. It is one of the 'tent pole' features of Mavericks.

Comment: You are right that it's not under-documented. But the question originally asked *"What are your favourite features in Mavericks?"*. It has since been *significantly* rephrased, thus pulling the rug out from underneath my answer.

Comment: I was looking forward to this feature, but actually find it doesn't work how I'd like it to at all. I expected each display would get its own row of workspaces, but it doesn't -- instead you keep the same number of workspaces all the time, divided between whatever displays are being used. One very annoying negative of this is that you can no longer drag a window off the edge of a display onto the neighbouring workspace any more, when using multiple displays.

Comment: @scottishwildcat - Yeah, that only works if the workspace you're dragging the window to is a desktop (as opposed to a full-screened app).

Comment: @scottishwildcat, I currently have Finder Safari and the desktop open on my main screen, And I'm just a desktop and another Safari window open on my external screen. So I don't understand what you mean by needing the same number of workspaces all the time. Also I can drag windows between desktops,  but obviously not from a desktop. And can drag tabs from a full screen Safari onto a desktop on another screen. Perhaps you haven't ticked the box "displays have separate screens" in mission control preferences?

Comment: I have that preference checked, and now I can no longer drag windows to other workspaces on the same display, without using Mission Control. This is annoying and I don't really understand why it's no longer possible.

Comment: As to the other point, hard to explain in a comment, but I was just surprised that when adding new workspaces on an external display, they didn't disappear again when I disconnected that display. So the external display doesn't have its 'own' workspaces as such, it just borrows from the main pool when connected. Which is a bit confusing, since when using a single display, that pool is conceptually arranged as a single row, but when you connect an external one, it suddenly splits into two rows with not necessarily the same number of workspaces in each.

Comment: The whole feature is kinda buggy at the moment o.O

Answer (score 33):

The battery menu in the top bar now shows apps using high amounts of energy - nice for killing energy-hogs:

[image]

Comment: I'ma swipe your picture for my answer on Activity Monitor... I hope you like the [source code](http://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/f8f82757-b2af-45bd-87a0-7318a3434757/view-source) I used to edit my post.

Answer (score 30):

### Move Dashboard in Mission Control

You can now drag to rearrange the Dashboard to move it between your desktop spaces and full screen apps. It can even be dragged to alternative monitors, providing that "Displays have separate Spaces" is enabled in System Preferences → Mission Control.

[image]

Comment: You can move Desktop 1, too. In Mountain Lion, you could only move Desktop 2 and up.

Comment: How did you make the GIF like that? That's clever!

Comment: @DanijelJ With [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) :)

Answer (score 30):

#### Mac App Store Notifications Now Include Multiple "Later" Options

You can choose from a handful of times in the future to remind you about pending updates from the Mac App Store.

[image]

Credit to this [reddit.com/r/mac post](http://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/1p1wgt/finally_they_fixed_this/).

Answer (score 24):

**Battery Life**

It's hard to beat getting an additional hour of use on a battery charge. I've been getting at least that much more use before having to plug in my 2012 MacBook Air. My experience matches up well with Apple's claim during the announcement keynote where the 13 inch Air from 2013 with Haswell benchmarked with another hour to an hour and a half of battery life just by installing Mavericks.

Comment: Is this really a new / undocumented feature? Do you know if there's any connection to the battery monitoring that [Undo points out](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106036/what-under-documented-features-have-you-stumbled-upon-in-mavericks/106092#106092)?

Comment: @shog9 This is the net effect of many fundamental hidden under the hood features of Mavericks. I'm not yet sure which of the [alphabet soup of features](http://cl.ly/S5fE) announced publicly today make this possible. This most certainly is part of the monitoring now in place to report energy use that both [Undo](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106092/5472) and [I](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106086/5472) have reported on this thread.

Comment: I don't believe that this is a valid answer. Linking a comparison between it an Win8 doesn't show us anything about what's improved since 10.8. Give us a list of features of what's caused this improvement.

Comment: Somebody is putting words in my mouth, and the answer is confusing. All I was trying to say is that the biggest immediate improvement since going to 10.9 is the improved battery life on my 2012 11" MBA. That is a fantastic feature. Getting better performance from my hardware by just upgrading some software is pretty amazing.

Comment: Could list; iTunes HD Playback Efficiency, Safari Power Saver, App Nap in more detail than is included from http://www.apple.com/osx/advanced-technologies/

Comment: This is not un(der)-document at all! They stressed this out a lot. :P

Comment: This question didn't state under documented when I posted my answer. I was about favorite Mavericks features.

Answer (score 24):

### Finder messages are now Notification Center alerts

Prior to Mavericks, alerts from Finder would show up as a modal window, however they now show as a Notification Center alert, such as below:

[image]

Answer (score 22):

**Disable App Nap on a per app basis in OS X Mavericks:**

You may or may not know that one of [the more discreet features in OSX Mavericks will be App Nap](https://www.apple.com/osx/advanced-technologies/).

**Apps will enter App Nap when they’re completely hidden from view by other apps and when they aren’t actively working**. This is a great way to reduce your running apps from killing your Mac’s battery life.

Also, **you may want certain apps to never enter App Nap**. This could be true for apps that are important to you but sometimes perform long non-interactive tasks.

To **prevent apps from entering App Nap, go to Finder -> Applications -> right click on the app** you want -> click on **Get Info** -> and look for the **option that says “Prevent App Nap” right under the copyright section**, as shown on the picture below:

[image]

Please note that said **option won’t be there for apps that don’t support App Nap**.

Comment: Don't all Cocoa apps support App Nap by default?

Comment: @Mark I believe that's what they said at WWDC - all Cocoa apps support it out of the box, but there are some API calls that can be implemented so your app knows about it..

Answer (score 21):

### Show Desktop using Trackpad now follows motion

Using the Show Desktop gesture, the motion of the windows now follows the motion of your fingers on the trackpad. No longer is it a set speed, you can move the windows at the exact speed of your fingers, and even pull them back half way through to cancel the motion.

Comment: I think this is probably my least favorite feature (that I've noticed so far).  It's the same for 5-finger swipe to launch pad, and a quick swipe is no longer smooth, it stutters before deciding on going to the launch pad or fading out of it.

Comment: Pure toy, usability disaster. The animation of hiding the windows serves no real purpose, it should be as brief as possible.

Comment: One of the best features. I enables you to have a quick look on your desktop without also doing the oposite gestures afterwards.

Answer (score 20):

### Gatekeeper shows most recent app in System Preferences

After Gatekeeper blocks an app, going to the relevant option in System Preferences shows the app name and a button that allows you to open the app.

[image: "Fantastical.app" was blocked from opening because it is not from an identified developer. 'Open Anyway']

This means it is no longer required for new users to know that clicking Open from the right-click menu will bypass Gatekeeper.

Comment: It still requires them to know about and be able to find the Gatekeeper security settings though. I’m ready to bet that almost all casual users won’t be able to run non-App-Store applications because of that.

Answer (score 19):

### Open PSDs directly in Safari

You can now preview PSD files (Photoshop Documents) directly in Safari without actually opening Preview, or even downloading the PSD to your Downloads folder.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "without downloading" but QuickLook works for PSDs in 10.8 too

Comment: @beroe Clearly OP means a PSD file online.

Comment: @beroe The quote was taken out of vital context: "downloading the PSD to your *Downloads folder*". …and yes, whilst QL has worked for PSDs, now they will display in Safari.

Answer (score 19):

**AirPlay display:**

The Apple TV makes it easy to see on your TV the media content that is on your Mac, such as to stream videos or photos.

In OS X Mountain Lion, you could also mirror your Desktop to the Apple TV, such as for presentations.

OS X Mavericks takes that to the next step, treating the Apple TV as just another monitor, so you can extend your desktop onto an Apple TV-connected TV or projector.

Comment: How well does this actually work?   I've struggled getting any usability from this...  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106264/airplay-quality-issue-from-macbook-pro

Answer (score 15):

### Enhanced Dictation

Enhanced Dictation allows **offline use** and continuous dictation with live feedback.

Great for those without Internet connections and those not wanting to have their dictation processed outside of their network.

[image: Dictation and Speech settings]

Comment: I've been using this quite a bit...  mostly because I enjoy the live feedback.

Comment: When I checked out this panel, I found Use Enhanced Dictation was already checked, but I didn't recall it downloading the offline data.  Clicking Off then On started the download… apparently.

Comment: Apparently it is checked by default, but it doesn't actually download the data until the first time you use dictation.

Comment: The Use Enhanced Dictation was not checked after I upgraded from Mac OS X 10.8. I also had dictation disabled in Mac OS X 10.8. The settings being upgraded may influence the initial state in Mac OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 15):

### ColorSync Utility: New Calculator

This little known included application continues to improve with a new colour Calculator.

[image: Colour Calculator]

Not new to Mavericks but certainly hidden, ColorSync continues to provide interactive 3D colour space visualisation for profiles.

[image: 3D colour space]

Comment: **WHOA**, that is super cool!

Comment: Color calculator isn't new; it's been there since 10.7 at least.

Comment: Thanks @kirb. Mavericks is the first time I have actively noticed the calculator. Have they changed anything in ColorSync Utility for this update?

Comment: @GrahamMiln, just compared side-by-side with 10.8; only change I could see was the new dropdown and checkbox at the bottom of the calculator.

Answer (score 11):

**Improved Multiple Screen Support**

It is pretty awesome having a menu bar on each screen and being able to full screen apps on a per screen basis. I never used full screen mode before since I always had the linen background on my other screen.

Comment: I was looking forward to this feature, but actually find it doesn't work how I'd like it to at all. I expected each display would get its own row of workspaces, but it doesn't -- instead you keep the same number of workspaces all the time, divided between whatever displays are being used. One very annoying negative of this is that you can no longer drag a window off the edge of a display onto the neighbouring workspace any more, when using multiple displays.

Comment: @scottishwildcat I may misunderstand your description but taken literally it’s the opposite of true: that’s *exactly* what Mavericks provides: each display has its own row of spaces now, and you can absolutely drag windows between spaces and screens, both when using multiple windows and when not.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Maybe I didn't describe what I expected very well (and it's probably not worth trying to explain again here), but I definitely can't just drag windows onto neighbouring workspaces on the same display any more, I have to use Mission Control for that now. I can only drag windows between displays.

Comment: @scottishwildcat Ah, now I see what you want. Yes, you indeed need Mission Control for that. Pity, but the old way of dragging between spaces was quite sluggish anyway.

Comment: I didn't even know you could do that, but I think thats worth losing to have a different set of Spaces for each screen.

Comment: @scottishwildcat You can still use Control → and Control ←, even while dragging, to switch spaces.

Comment: @JPP Doesn't work for me... aside from the fact Ctrl and arrow keys are on opposite sides of my MBP keyboard so I wouldn't have any hands left to drag anything if I had to do that, as soon as I start dragging, my 'switch workspace' shortcuts (which luckily I redefined to Cmd+Alt+arrow many years ago) stop working.

Comment: @Jonathan I don't understand why we need to lose it all, though. I can't see any reason it shouldn't still work with the new model.

Comment: @scottishwildcat Did you check the Missing Control shortcuts in the Keyboard pref pane?

Comment: @scottishwildcat, because when you drag a window to the edge of the screen should it go to the external monitor or to the next space of the current monitor? Most people will expect it to go to the other monitor.

Comment: @Jonathan I have my monitors arranged vertically, and OS X knows that because I had to tell it, so that shouldn't be an issue in my case at least.

Answer (score 11):

**Driving directions for iOS:**

OS X Mavericks adopts iOS's Maps app. That by itself is not a huge deal, even though it's nice to have an alternative to Google's Web-based maps. But what's cool is the ability to get driving directions and send them to your iPhone or other iOS 7-based device. They show up in the iOS Maps app, ready for you to follow while driving or walking, and they remain in your bookmarked directions for access later if needed.

Comment: How does it transfer these? I would have originally thought AirDrop, but AirDrop on OS X is not compatible with AirDrop on iOS. Bluetooth? Some iCloud magic?

Answer (score 11):

New Safari setting to power off plugins when inactive to save battery life as featured in this Ars Technica [article](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/mavericks-an-operating-system-in-pictures/).

I have high expectations that this will stop the issues occurring when my girlfriend has 15 tabs with flash players open in the background while working in other programs.

Comment: But will it stop the issues when the girlfriend has 15 tabs with flash players open in the background... in Firefox?

Comment: @Michael No. In that case you will have to change to a newer version of girlfriend that supports Safari.

Answer (score 11):

**Easily Identify New Apps:**

If you use Launchpad, any new apps you download will sparkle to denote their newness.

Once you acknowledge them, or they've sat there neglected for awhile, the sparkles will disappear.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

### Move Dock Between Monitors

The Dock starts on your main monitor, but if you put your cursor in another monitor, go to the bottom of the screen, and then keep moving down, the Dock will pop up (and disappear from wherever it was previously).  This is really nice if your "main" monitor isn't actually.

The motion has to be pretty straight down and surprisingly long - it's a bit finicky.

Comment: This is applicable only if your dock is at the bottom (I have it on the left).

Comment: @rm-rf True; if you use the left/right options it is locked to the left/right side of the left-/right-most monitor.

Comment: @AaronDufour How do you disable this feature?

Comment: @AlexejMagura I haven't found a way to disable it.  Feel free to add it if you find one.

Answer (score 10):

### Responsive scrolling

In Mountain Lion and earlier, any window content that doesn't fit in the current frame of the window (like a long webpage) isn't drawn until scrolled into view. In Mavericks, this offscreen content is ["pre-rendered" during idle time](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/os-x-10-9/19/#responsive-scrolling), which results in vastly improved scrolling performance (especially noticeable with complex documents or webpages).

Comment: In general, though, I've found the scrolling performance, at least in Safari, significantly more sluggish (Macbook Air 11" 2012). Was trying to see if someone had a trick for disabling Timer Coalescing to see if that was the culprit.

Answer (score 10):

**Disable Notification Center on the Lock Screen:**

[image]

Notification Center doesn't see a whole lot of improvement this time around, but the update does mess with your settings a little bit. If you're not a fan of getting a million notifications, you're going to want to pop into **System Preferences > Notifications** and take a look at the new options. The **big one** to check is **"Show notifications on lock screen."**

If you don't want your emails or anything else showing when you're computer is locked, uncheck this box.

Comment: If you want nothing, you have to uncheck the box for each separate application? That's a pain… why can't it be a global setting?!

Answer (score 10):

### Zoom pictures in QuickLook

You can now zoom pictures in QuickLook using the default zoom gestures: Pinch In & Pinch Out, as well as panning with two fingers.

Comment: Pressing alt works as well

Comment: @Agos Pressing alt has worked since forever afaik…

Answer (score 10):

### Debug menus have been updated

The debug menus have been updated for various apps.

<sub>Below is the debug menu for App Store and Contacts:</sub>

[image]
[image]

---

To activate the menus, run the following commands (and restart the apps):

```
defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
defaults write com.apple.AddressBook ABShowDebugMenu -bool true
```

Replace `true` with `false` to remove.

Comment: How to activate these menus?

Comment: @hashier See Terminal commands in edit.

Comment: Do you now a `defaults` that activates this on ALL application? Or do you know any more applications where I can activate it?

Comment: @hashier Unfortunately, the key is slightly different for each app, so the `-g` (global) flag doesn't work… Many of Apple's apps include a debug menu, including Safari (different from the Develop menu), Disk Utility, Calendar, and many more. I seem to remember a list of apps and their relevant defaults key required to enable it, however I can't find it at the moment. Once I find it I'll edit the post and ping you - until then, Google `[app name] debug menu` to see if/what the command is for enabling the menu for each app. Don't forget this works for some 3rd-party apps too :)

Comment: In Safari there's an option in the preferences to enable the Debug menu.

Comment: @Martin There's an option to enable the *Develop* menu, which is substantially different to the Debug menu :)

Comment: @grgarside damn, I must stop reading this late at night… ;)

Answer (score 8):

iCloud Keychain stores and syncs Secure Notes across Macs.

The new iCloud Keychain stores website usernames and passwords, credit card numbers and Wi-Fi network information and keeps the data up to date across all of a person's Apple devices, including the iPhone and iPad.

It also stores and syncs Secure Notes across Macs, like this:
[image: Secure Note]

Answer (score 6):

### Notification Center appears on current monitor

In a multi-monitor setup, Notification Center now appears on the monitor where your cursor is currently located. This is a nice improvement if you invoke it while you're working on a secondary monitor: it appears on the monitor you're looking at, rather than the primary.

Comment: Extra points if someone can find a trick to disable that.  I like all my notifications and crap to be on the other monitor so I have one for pure work.

Answer (score 6):

You can now sort your documents in Finder even when you have the grouping feature turned on. (For example you group the download folder by filetype and files inside the group are sorted by name)

Answer (score 5):

Now you can see which all apps are using your location. And you will also a new Privacy tab in Security & Privacy in System Preferences :

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Safari tells you when a tab crashed

Whilst Safari has always been able to restart crashed tabs, now it tells you when it's done so:

[image]

Comment: Now that is both cool and useful to have.

Answer (score 4):

**Messages (iMessages) can be created quickly in Notification Center**

Answer (score 4):

Full screen finder:

[image]

Pretty simple, but really nice.

Comment: still no two finger swipe for back and forward though :(

Comment: … and apparently no hotkeys for switching between tabs? I thought the whole point of tabs here was that they behave exactly as in Safari …

Comment: @KonradRudolph cmd + shift + { works for me

Comment: @fuadksd So it does. I could have sworn that Safari has a different combination. Still kind of annoying that there’s no agreed-on standard, so that all other application use different keys (in particular Firefox, Chrome, Opera using ⌘+⌥+arrow keys (EDIT: I just realise that they also support Safari’s style).

Comment: It supports both cmd + {|} and ctrl + shift + tab. Those are supported by safari, and I think, they're like, Cocoa standards.

Comment: ctrl + tab works, however it doesn't in Safari? +1 for same shortcuts in all apps!

Comment: ctrl + tab works in Safari

Answer (score 4):

**Using Speakable Items and Automator To Command Your Mac By Voice:**

The Unofficial Apple Weblog (TUAW) uses an automator script and the new "Speakable Items" option in Mavericks to achieve this:

System Preferences > Accessibility > Speakable Items to launch apps.

When it's set up, you simply hit a key on your keyboard, speak a phrase, and that launches the apps you choose.

Their example is a simple "Good morning" to start your day.

There is a list of preprogrammed things you can say to command your Mac as well.

They have a [video tutorial](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/10/23/os-x-mavericks-video-tip-using-automator-and-speakable-items-to/) which takes you through the various steps.

Answer (score 4):

Fairly certain that System Preferences has had some visual tweaks, including larger text and icons. There's a new iCloud icon too.

*Edit: As per comments, the category titles have been removed.*

[image: prefs]

Comment: They removed the category titles from each section, too.

Answer (score 4):

LinkedIn and few others are now supported in Internet Accounts :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Automatically Installs Updates

My favorite feature is the ability to have updates install automatically in the background just like they do in iOS 7.

Answer (score 4):

## Charging state of an iPad is notified to the user

Because of insufficient current on some Macs, especially older ones or because of USB multipliers, iPads can't get charged or they only get charged when their screen is idle.

Of course, Mavericks can't fix this situation, it's basically an electrical problem but it seems that Apple now made it a little bit more manageable by notifying the user through a Notification Center message if their iPad is not being charged when plugged to their Mac.

[image]

Comment: I had no idea that some Macs could charge iPads - charging works with Retina Macbook Pro late 2013.

Answer (score 4):

### Finder Tabs

Safari Style

[image]

- Command + T opens a new tab (as it does in Safari)
- Right click (or control + click) a file or folder within a finder window > "open in Tab"
- Control + Tab to cycle through each
- Bunch of open Finder windows?  Window > "Merge all Windows" to neatly arrange into one Finder window with tabs.

Answer (score 4):

### Activity Monitor tells you what pages a Safari process has open

If you mouseover any Safari subprocess in Activity Monitor you can see what pages are loaded in the process in the tooltip.

Answer (score 3):

The Mail.app for Mavericks supports exporting emails now as PDF files, which is useful. Although if attempting to export multiple emails as PDF, it will simply generate multiple PDF's rather than appending one large PDF file.

Answer (score 3):

**Disable Mavericks Spelling Autocorrection**:

If you get frustrated when OS X 10.9 attempts to autocorrect the multiple technology words that it doesn’t recognize. You should be able to disable the autocorrection feature either globally or on a per application basis.

In theory you should be able to disable it globally or disable it only in certain applications. I have not found that the global disable actually seems to turn off the corrections in all applications though. this is most probably a bug that will be fixed in future Mavericks updates.  It is helpful to disable it only in specific applications anyway.

*Disable Spelling Autocorrection in all Applications*:

- Select **Keyboards** under **System Preferences**.
- Under the **Text** tab uncheck **correct spelling automatically**.

*Disable Autocorrection for a Specific Application*:

- Open the Apple application that you want autocorrection disabled.
- Right-click (or ctrl-click) into any text field. From the context menu that appears, under **Spelling and Grammar** uncheck **Correct Spelling Automatically**.

[image]

Remember that various applications can handle spelling correction in multiple different ways. Many applications will maintain the consistency of OS X and have this option available when right-clicking (ctrl-clicking) a text field. Disabling autocorrection in Chrome, for example, is handled this way.

Other applications such as Firefox may require you hunting through the Preferences to disable the autocorrection feature.

Answer (score 2):

**iCloud Sync:**

Automator and AppleScript Editor, both apps have been updated with iCloud compatibility. AppleScripts that you've created or Automator workflows can now be moved into the cloud and synced to all of your Macs that are running OS X Mavericks.

It's useful if you're creating and updating scripts or workflows that need to be deployed to a handful of Macs automatically.

Answer (score 2):

**Show Twitter feed in Safari's Sidebar**

Update: It's not the complete feed, just messages with URLs embedded in them.

Being able to see your twitter feed in a Safari Sidebar is pretty cool, and definitely under documented.

1. Add your Twitter credentials to the "Internet Accounts" panel of "System Preferences."
2. Click on the "open book" icon in the new Safari bookmark bar.
3. Select "Shared Links" or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>^⌘3</kbd> to toggle "Shared Links".

I believe that this is all that I did to be able to see my twitter feed in the safari sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

Messages now has a color setting called auto, which will color the messages of the person you're talking to in the way that they color their own messages.

Comment: This has existed for ages, right? I'm sure I used that back in Snow Leopard, and possibly before?… (At least with iChat)

Comment: Oh yup, you're right, I just checked my mountain lion machine. Maybe it just defaulted to that setting when I upgraded and I never noticed.  So then it's just a cool under-documented feature of OSX hahah

Answer (score 2):

This not exactly a useful feature, Java seems to be not installed by default and when you try to check java version in terminal, it takes you to the download page. Run this in terminal : `java -version`

[image]

as a feature, I find this quickest way to install Java :P

Comment: This was also the case in Lion and Mountain Lion, I believe.

Comment: Isn't it unsafe to install Java or something ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hidden Dock won’t appear in fullscreen apps:**

You may find that the Dock won’t show up from the bottom or right/left side (depending on where you put it) when apps are in fullscreen, and when you fast-move the cursor to where your Dock is hidden or when you pause right there and let the cursor hover. No Dock.

**Here’s the trick:**

You need to move the cursor very slowly. That’s all you need to do. If you move it too fast to the edge of your screen, the Dock won’t show up.

Answer (score 2):

### Side dock has new UI

It now looks like this (I really like the light that indicates which apps are open, it's a lot more clearer than the bottom dock):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Event reminders based on travel time

When you create an event in Calendar, you can specify a location. If the address is recognized, it'll insert a map right in the event details (and even give you the current weather conditions!).

But it goes even further. Calendar can also determine your current location, so you can tell it to calculate the *travel time* to the event based on where you currently are. If you do, that gives you a new alert option: "when I need to leave."

This is *so* much better than the old fixed-time options (1 hour before, 30 minutes before, etc.) because it's dynamic based on where you are and how far you need to drive.

Answer (score 0):

Did someone noticed that the *Remove from Dock* option on the Trash icon's context menu in the Dock is gone. I clicked that a couple of times accidentally and then had to [bring it back](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4858501) in Mountain Lion.

Answer (score -14):

iBooks (for Mac) stinks (can't edit any metadata, kinda flakey about syncing with my iPad, you now have to interact with two programs to manage your books, etc.), but if you were unfortunate enough to have it suck all of your books out of iTunes and into its universe before you knew what was going on then here are a couple of tips.

To delete a book or PDF select the book and hit the Delete key.  (There was something in iTunes that worked in that same non-intuitive way, wasn't there?)

To reduce the the flakiness of the sync I had to double-home-button-kill iBooks on my iPad, then try syncing again.  It helped.

If out of habit you drag a PDF into iTunes it will be gladly accepted, but you won't be able to see it anymore, because the Books category is gone and there's no Library category anymore.  It will show up as Music and you can delete it from there.

UPDATE: 9:30pm: NOW there's a "Delete" item showing up when you right-click on a book in the popup menu.  That hasn't been there all day.  Have no idea what made it start showing up.  This program needs some work.  It should have been iBooks beta.

Comment: This might work better as a stand-alone question where you state the issues you have and how you have tried to solve them.