# Returning to simple pop-up characters panel?

Tags: keyboard, macos, internationalization, emoji

One of my favorite new Mavs features is the pop-up characters panel.  Its operation is detailed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106291/21050). It is summoned via <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and looks like this:

[image: pop-up characters panel]

At some point, however, the key combination started summoning the full Character Viewer instead:

[image: Character Viewer window]

The latter is a bit more awkward to use than the panel was.  How did I get set this way and how I can get back to using the pop-up panel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button in the upper-right corner of Character Viewer was the culprit.  If I summon Character Viewer and click it, Character Viewer shrinks:

[image: smaller Character Viewer]

From then on, further presses of <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> summon the pop-up panel instead.

As to how I got to the full Character Viewer, opening Character Viewer from the menu bar Input menu (which can be turned on in System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources):

[image: Input menu]

then clicking the button in the upper-right corner of Character Viewer twice—once to shrink the window, once to restore it—appears to set a preference that I'd like the key combination to pop up the full Character Viewer instead of the pop-up.