# Poor battery stats on rMBP late-2013

Tags: battery, macbook-pro

I unpacked my new MacBook only 2 days ago and it showed 9-10 hours of battery life (as advertised). I didn't calibrate it, since it is no longer necessary (I was told).

Today I noticed that it started to show only 4 hours of battery life with 98% charge. I am a student and it shows me these stats when I run *nothing* - I am not editing photos, watching movies, etc. I only had I tab in a browser (Chrome) opened.

Do you know, why is that? Should I check with Apple if my battery is somehow faulty?

I am a first time MacBook owner.

Answer (score 3):

- Check the Energy tab of Activity Monitor and look for processes that have a high energy usage.

  [image]

  <sup>[Screenshot Source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106086/37797)</sup>
- Leave it for a bit longer (up to a week) to see if there's any change.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the activity monitor (can be found in Utilities) and see on the energy tab if there are processes running in background that consume much energy. If there's nothing listed you could also check the complete process list on the CPU tab.

If your MacBook has two graphics cards, the one with higher energy consumption might be currently running. This tool can show which card is in use: http://gfx.io/. Using the second graphics card decreases battery life a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. What you should check is, go to system information, and go to power. Put a screenshot here.

It should include cycles, charge capacity, etc.

Put it here so we can see what's going on.