# How can I force Safari to Save As webpage?

Tags: macos, safari

Sometimes, you can't save the page you want (actually I don't know why this happens).
How can I force the Safari to **Save As**?

URL:[What features of Mavericks are beneficial to you?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106036/what-features-of-mavericks-are-beneficial-to-you)

[image]

Comment: do you have an example of a URL where you have the problem?

Comment: @LaurentBristiel Question has been edited.

Comment: hmm, interesting...do you have a JS setting that would prevent that ? (javaScript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know the reason and don't reproduce the problem. But according to [this question](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4991027) you should be able to override this by clicking on option at the same time.

Comment: that worked for me. Save As... was greyed out unless I held option.

Comment: Actually you don’t have to hold `Option` in order to use `Save As`. It’s greyed out because you haven’t focused the cursor to the page. `Command+S` should probably work without using `Option` too.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when the page hasn't actually finished loading.  Try pressing command-[period] to stop it loading, then try saving the page.

Answer (score 0):

If others are trying to save an audio or video file that is opened directly in a tab, try to focus the location bar and press option-return.

If you open an audio or video file in Safari, select Save As, and set the format to Page Source, Safari just saves an empty file.